# How to filter records in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table called "Status" as shown below in sql server.

[image]

How can I filter the records where the timestamp is less then 5 minutes for the same Level and same Status?

Eg: For the above records my output should be like

[image]

Comment: Define "remove" and define "efficient". Also include your existing sql statement and include why that is "not efficient"

Comment: I've updated my question for better understanding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `lag()`:

```
select s.*
from (select s.*, lag(date) over (partition by level, status order by date) as prev_date
      from status s
     ) s
where prev_date is null or
      prev_date > dateadd(minute, -5, date);
```